# Powershell Excel Automation - Save/Open fails in Scheduled Task

Tags: excel, powershell, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I created a simple powershell script that will create an excel instance and save a workbook:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\foo.xls")
$workbook.SaveAs("C:\Test\bar.xls")

# cleanup code ...
```

When I run this from powershell directly it works fine.
I created a scheduled task that runs it, and when I have the option set that will "Run only when the user is logged in" then it will run fine.

When I change this option to run whether the user is logged in or not, it will fail trying to open/save the file. The account I am using has the correct permissions. I have the account set up to Log in as a service.

Any suggestions?

Comment: would this be related? Similar issue on Server 2008 with running a PS script as a Scheduled Task: http://www.techdecode.com/wp/?p=58

Comment: In some cases, since there seems to be no exception thrown on the call to Open, the next logical step is often to access the Workbooks property, and at that point the error message that came up in the log was "Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks class" . So anyone who runs into that should look to this issue to see if it explains and solves their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember having to do something similar in a C# application, which went well when you build it on Visual Studio, but running under a service on the CI server failed. This I believe is the limitation of Office Automation itself and Microsoft doesn't recommend / support doing this at all Look at Considerations for server-side Automation of Office here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757. It shows the problems and the alternatives.

In my case, I had to give up Office Interop, and use EPPlus ( http://epplus.codeplex.com/ ) to work with excel. It worked great and was much faster as well.

Answer (score 14):

I've been burned by this and didn't want to rewrite the code. I saw your post and several others which made me about to give up. However, my persistence paid off. I was trying to have Jenkins run a script to inventory our production environment and output to Excel. I didnt want a text doc because I was highlighting software versions that didnt match in RED, so needed Excel.

**Here is the answer that worked for me:**

> You have to create a folder (or two on a 64bit-windows):

(32Bit, always)

> C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

(64Bit)

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

Link that someone provided as the source:

> http://www.patton-tech.com/2012/05/printing-from-scheduled-task-as.html

My source was:

> http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverpowershell/thread/aede572b-4c1f-4729-bc9d-899fed5fad02

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing :) Good to note that the desktop folder needs to be created.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, but I did want to mention, you have a typo in your 32-bit path. You wrote 'Dektop' instead of 'Desktop" (note the **S**)

Comment: I can't believe I just had to add these two folders to make this work. Many thanks!

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer for this post. Only the link to patton-tech is not working anymore, but was not useful anyway

Comment: This is so stupid, but it indeed works LOL