# Python Excel automation through Jenkins

Tags: python, excel, jenkins, pywin32, win32com

I'm using win32 python library to automate an excel doc generation. I'm also using Jenkins to run the python script that will generate the doc.

I'm facing a problem with the "SaveAs" function. Whenever I run the python script from my local machine it generates and saves the doc successfully. However, when I trigger the script from jenkins, it fails when the "SaveAs is invoked".

This is my very simple python code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from win32com.client import constants

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = False
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
wb.SaveAs(r"D:\HelloWorld.xlsx")
excel.Quit()
```

As you can see in both pictures, the python invocation is the same, yet it only succeeds on my local machine.
Notes:
I tried changing the jenkins user to SYSTEM then to LOCAL ACCOUNT but nothing worked.
I also tried to chmod the file directory but didn't work either.

[image: jenkins]
[image: local]
Update: I need to add checkboxes in the excel sheet, and as far as I know this is only possible through comtypes library or pywin32 library. If there are any other options please direct me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112967/powershell-excel-automation-save-open-fails-in-scheduled-task/13369587#13369587

Answer (score 0):

Try writing excel without using com object.

I recommend [xlsxwriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter)  but there are also other alternatives

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add in the post that I intended to add checkboxes to the excel sheet. After lots of googling, I realized that this is not possible except through pywin32 or comtypes library. Are there any other alternatives??

Comment: It's worth checking the docs. The package is very comprehensive. The only thing I needed and didn't find was pivot tables.

Comment: I just downloaded the whole package and skimmed through the doc files, but there's nothing at all about checkboxes or any other ole objects... only charts and textboxes ....if you stumbled upon any library that does so, please let me know .... thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess but are you running Jenkins as a windows service? If yes then try to run it via command line and try. Jenkins running as service does does have issues when launching windows/browsers.

Comment: Yes actually I'm running it as service! I will try to run it through command line, hopefully this would not present any limitations opposed to running it as a service.