# "Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks class" when automated

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I have some PowerShell scripts that invoke SQL commands, take the results and put them into a CSV file, then the CSV file is put into an excel workbook and it's emailed out to a distribution list. I had no issues running these reports through Windows Scheduled tasks on my older Windows 2008 server running SQL 2008. But I have migrated over to Windows 2016 running SQL 2016. Now when I run this process through Scheduled tasks I get the following error:

```
Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks class
At C:\PowerShell\scrpits\ArtiReport3.ps1:607 char:1
+ $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($csvFilePath)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

If I run the PowerShell script manually I have no issues and everything runs fine. I'm using the same login to run the scripts manually as I do through scheduled tasks. Here is the script.

```
$query = "*SQL Query runs here*"

#Edit these peramters for the server this will be running on#
$smtpServer = "*server*";
$smtpFrom = "I3Reports@server.com";
$smtpTo = "*email list here*”
$messageSubject = "I3 Report";

#create anonymus loging for sending e-mail#
$User = "anonymous";
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "anonymous" -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pword


$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$date = $date+"_I3Report.xls";

$csvFilePath = "c:\Scripts\queryresults.csv"
$excelFilePath = "c:\scripts\$date"


$instanceName = "*server*"
Import-Module "sqlps"
$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -QueryTimeout 7200 -Query $query -ServerInstance $instanceName

# Output to CSV
$results | export-csv  $csvFilePath -Delimiter "    " -NoTypeInformation
#this line will remove all the quotation marks from the csv file
(Get-Content $csvFilePath) | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file -FilePath $csvFilePath -Force 

# Convert CSV file to Excel


$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$excel.visible = $False 
$excel.displayalerts=$False 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($csvFilePath) #<-- Program fails here
$workSheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1) 
#$workSheet.cells.item(3,3) = "HOPLA"

#for freezing pane#
$workSheet.application.activewindow.splitcolumn = 0
$workSheet.application.activewindow.splitrow = 1
$workSheet.Range("A2").application.activewindow.freezepanes = $true
$resize = $workSheet.UsedRange 
$resize.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null 
$xlExcel8 = 43
$workbook.SaveAs($excelFilePath, $xlExcel8)
$workbook.Close()
$excel.quit() 
$excel = $null

send-mailmessage -from $smtpFrom -to $smtpTo -subject "$messageSubject" -body "Attachment" -Attachments $excelFilePath -smtpServer $smtpServer -Credential $creds;
```

As mentioned this works when I run it in PowerShell manually, but through scheduled tasks it gets that error and it references the section I noted in the code. I've been working on this for days and I can't seem to figure out what is causing the issue. Any help or suggestions is welcomed. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to [SO]. Please take the [tour]. What about using [Doug Finkes ImportExcel module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) to directly generate the ExcelFile from `$Results` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what options that excel module provides, but I need to be able to change the cells formatting and do freeze panes and other excel tasks. And I have a lot of these scripts, there are many reports that run. I would have to edit all the reports if I switched over to it. I'm just wondering why I can run them manually without issues but scheduling them fails with the above error.

Comment: IMO the way over a csv is cumbersome compared to the .xlsx file generated by Export-Excel (with parms -FreezeTopRow, -Autosize -Autofilter). You still could modify the Excel file with powershell.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution to this problem here

[Powershell Excel Automation - Save/Open fails in Scheduled Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112967/powershell-excel-automation-save-open-fails-in-scheduled-task?rq=1)

Creating the folders and gaining access to the directories that they are in did it for me.